# Firebase deep linking asks if I want to open the link in app or continue in browser, React Native

Tags: firebase, react-native, deep-linking, firebase-dynamic-links

I don't want such behaviour how to disable modal asking if I want to open the link in app or continue in browser?
When I try to open any other link not handled by firebase (ex: facebook) it opens normally, without asking.